# JVM performance and thread load and profiling to optimize performance in Java based project

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, performance, jvm

My question is related to find out performance issues for Java based  web project with MySQL backend.
I want to check JVM performance what is best way to get JMX values.

How to check thread performance like how many threads are running in one transaction and where is the bottleneck related to 
  Resource Starving threads ,  Blocking thread if any,
  Objects / classes load and unload time and sizes. 
I am  using Packetbeat Logstash with Kibana to collect log and monitoring but didn't find this info.

Is there any shortcut or simple way to check these performance issues?

If my question is vague please let me know I will try to add more details.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) packaged along with your jdk to monitor the Threads , GC , etc to analyze the JVM performance . If you want more fine grained details , go with some JVM profiling tools like [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/)

Comment: Thanks Saril, It will help in development or does it work on production similar to new relic reporting ? in terms of JVM monitoring or thread profiling. is it open source ? thanks for help

Comment: VisualVM helps in development and its freeware . For production I would suggest to go with any APM tool like appdynamics if your budget allows

Comment: Thanks Saril, I will be evaluate few APM tools. I think there are no open source APM tools like appdynamics or new rellic.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use JProfiler .JProfiler works both as a stand-alone application and as a plug-in for the Eclipse software development environment.
But JProfiler is licensed one.

Comment: Thanks Fahin, my project is in production. and I want some way that it should display these monitoring results in real time, most preferably in web. I think this tool works when your project is in development env. Please correct me if I am wrong.